# "Java Sound Event Dispatcher" Thread does not exit

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, microphone, recording

Ive written a Recording tool in Java with the TargetDataLine Class, but the problem is, if i close the TargaDataLine a Thread called "Java Sound Event Dispatcher" is still on WAITING status, the Thread appears after TargaDataLine::open. I didn't find anything about it except a post on a bug report page from OpenJDK (see: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4365713). Does anyone have a fix for that ?

Code:

```
this.targetDataLine = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(AudioUtil.getAudioFormat());
this.targetDataLine.open(AudioUtil.getAudioFormat()); //Thread[Java Sound Event Dispatcher,5,main] starts here
this.targetDataLine.start();

//Recording code... 

this.targetDataLine.flush();
this.targetDataLine.close();
// Thread[Java Sound Event Dispatcher,5,main] is still there, but on WAITING status
```

Comment: From the bug report you linked to: `"Affects Version/s: 1.3.0 Date: 08/24/2000"`  I really think you need to find a slightly more recent bug report.  Better yet post some code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i added now a code example ^^